# Excess contribution to 403b

Tags: united-states, retirement-plan, excess-contribution, 403b

We had 39000 taken out from our payroll last year and put into the company 403b plan.  Now we realize that this is more than the 25000 allowed.  (19000 + 6000 over 50 years old)  How can we handle this over amount of 14000?

Comment: In the question you use the phrase "We", but do you mean "you".

Comment: Does the company belong to you as in "our payroll"? Or is it that you are an employee of a company that is not under your direct control? Usually, company payroll systems cut off contributions to 403(b) or 401(k) plans when then limit is reached.

Comment: I had 39000 taken from my payroll.  Excess amount of 14000 was taken out for me as employee